# Diferença entre Any, Contains e Exists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lista

Qual a diferença entre `Any`, `Contains` e `Exists`?

Qual o contexto apropriado para cada um deles? (Exemplos de uso)

Qual as vantagens e desvantagens?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## TL;DR;

Todos eles checam se um elemento existe numa determinada coleção de elementos, porém de maneiras diferentes.

`Any()` veio com o Linq, funciona com qualquer coleção enumerável e recebe `Func<T, bool>` como parâmetro. O `Any()` também tem uma versão sem parâmetro nenhum que verifica se a coleção contém algum elemento, ou seja, se `Count > 0`.

`Exists()` funciona apenas com `List<T>` e recebe um `Predicate<T>` como parâmetro - isso permite que sejam feitas duas ou mais validações. Ex.: `lista.Exists(x => x == 1 || x == 2);`

`Contains()` também funciona apenas com `List<T>`, mas ao invés de receber um `Predicate<T>` recebe um elemento (`T`) como parâmetro.

---

Supondo que você tem uma lista de inteiros

```
var lista = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

### [`Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx)

É um método de extensão do *namespace* `System.Linq`. Veio com o .NET Framework 3.5 e funciona com qualquer coleção que seja "enumerável". Recebe `Func<T, bool>`  como parâmetro (na prática é a mesma coisa que receber `Predicate<T>`).

Ex. de uso (verificar se existem os elementos 2 ou 3):

```
bool existe = lista.Any(x => x == 2 || x == 3);
```

### [`Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Método padrão de `List<T>`. Recebe um elemento como parâmetro.

Ex. de uso (verificar se existe o elemento 1):

```
bool existe = lista.Contains(1);
```

### [`Exists()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bfed8bca(v=vs.110).aspx)

Também é um método padrão de `List<T>`. A única diferença dele pro `Contains` é que ele recebe um `Predicate<T>` como parâmetro, ao invés de receber um elemento. Ele existe basicamente para que não seja necessário fazer vários `Contains()` quando precisar verificar a existência de mais de um elemento numa lista.

Ex. de uso (verificar se existem os elementos 1 ou 3):

```
bool exists = lista.Exists(x => x == 1 || x == 3);
```

Answer (score 17):

[`Any()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) - Determina se algum, qualquer um, elemento de uma coleção enumerável atende uma condição especificada.

```
lista.Any(x => x == 1)
```

[`Contains()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_) - É um caso especial do `Any()`, em vez de estabelecer uma condição parametrizada ele já tem uma condição definida, ele pega o elemento e faz uma comparação de igualdade para saber se existe um elemento na lista que tenha aquele valor (note que o parâmetro não é um predicado, não receberá uma *lambda* mas sim um objeto). Ele pode ter uma performance melhor em alguns tipos de coleção, se esta limitação dele atender. Tem uma sintaxe obviamente mais simples.

```
lista.Contains(1)
```

[`Exists()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.exists?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Exists_System_Predicate__0__) - É o mesmo que o `Any()` mas existia antes do LINQ ser inventado para um `List`, não para outros enumeráveis. Em geral deve ser evitado.

```
lista.Exists(x => x == 1)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/ContainsXExistsXAny.cs).

Todos exemplos são equivalentes. Obviamente outros exemplos podem ser inviáveis nas três opções.

Answer (score 12):

`Exists` é um método de uma classe (acho que `List`) que verifica se um elemento está presente nessa lista, e está presente desde o .NET 2.0. Foi criado para ser usado com `delegate`, mas funciona com lambdas. Só funciona com listas, e deve ser (mais não tenho certeza) mais otimizado que os demais (por ser mais específico, mas posso estar falando besteira).

```
minhaLista.Exists(x => x.Contains("abc"));
```

`Any` veio com .NET 3.5 e foi criado para usar com LINQ. É um *extension method* que funciona com qualquer `IEnumerable` (basicamente, qualquer *Collection*, incluindo as classes que você criar que implementam `IEnumerable`).

```
meuEnumerable.Any(); // Tem algum elemento?
meuEnumerable.Any(x => x.Contains("abc")); // Tem algum elemento com "abc"?
```

`Contains` tem as mesmas características do `Any` (.NET 3.5, LINQ), mas você utiliza um `IEqualityComparer` para fazer a comparação (ao invés de um lambda). Acho isso útil quando você tem que fazer a mesma comparação em vários lugares.

```
// Vou utilizar essa comparação parcial em vários lugares. Para
// evitar escrever o lambda do exemplo anterior em todo lugar,
// uso isso. Facilita refatorar, evita duplicação.
// Especialmente útil para comparações mais complexas
class PartialEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<String> {

    public bool Equals(String x, String y) {
        return x.Contains(y);
    }

    // GetHashCode...
}

meuEnumerable.Contains("abc", new PartialEqualityComparer());
```