# Not In Linq Sql Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Preciso fazer o Nessa pesquisa, porém apresenta o erro:

> ambiguous invocation.

```
public List<Notification> Get(List<UserVisualization> item)
{
    return db.Notifications.Select(o=> o.EntityId).Where(o => !item.Contains(o.EntityId)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que quando você faz **`db.Notifications.Select(o => o.EntityId)`** o retorno é um `int` (supondo que este seja o tipo de `EntityId`) e você está aplicando o `Where` no retorno no `Select`. Portanto, o argumento **`o`** dentro do `Where` é um `int` e não um tipo complexo.

Fora isso, você não pode aplicar um `Contains` de um `int` dentro de uma lista de um tipo complexo. Possivelmente você quer comparar alguma propriedade.

Só mudar a ordem do `Select` e do `Where` **e arrumar o `Contains` (explico abaixo)** deve resolver. Com mais detalhes, posso melhorar a resposta.

O `Contains` precisa ser trocado por `Any`, porque ele recebe um elemento e não um `Func<T, bool>`. [Você pode ver mais nessa publicação.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103063/18246)

```
return db.Notifications.Where(o => !item.Any(x => x.Propriedade == o.EntityId))
                       .Select(o => o.EntityId).ToList();
```

Na verdade, você pode evitar de ter que inverter as operações fazendo deste jeito

```
return db.Notifications.Select(o => o.EntityId)
                       .Where(entityId => !item.Any(x => x.Propriedade == entityId));
```

Comment: Perfeito. O Any deu certo. Valeu  @jbueno