# Verificar se existe valor em List

Tags: c#, lista, contains

Estou tentando, fazer uma condição, onde verificaria, se em um `List` existe um valor, então criei o seguinte:

```
  private void Itens_Edit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(editar == 1)
        {
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(gridView5.GetRowCellValue(gridView5.GetSelectedRows()[0], "ITEM"));
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(gridView5.GetRowCellValue(gridView5.GetSelectedRows()[0], "QUANTIDADE"));              

            // se o item editado, conter na lista editable, adiciona na lista edit, para fazer update
            if (List_Itens_Editable.Contains(a))
            {
                // se não existir na lista edit, adiciona se nao nao.
                if(!item_edit.Contains(new Part_edit { item = a}))
                {
                    item_edit.Add(new Part_edit { item = a, qnt = b});
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

porem, a condição:

```
if(!item_edit.Contains(new Part_edit { item = a}))
```

Sempre é valida, mesmo ja existindo o valor na lista

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `Contains`, naturalmente, faz uso da implementação de `IEquatable` caso a classe em questão implemente esta interface, caso contrário, ele faz uso do método `Equals` da classe.

Se você não implementou `IEquatable` e nem sobrescreveu o método `Equals` o comportamento padrão será verificar se existe um elemento da lista que seja **exatamente o mesmo do que foi passado por parâmetro**, ou seja, se as duas variáveis apontam para o mesmo objeto.

Você cria um novo objeto para passar por parâmetro, ou seja, o resultado **sempre** vai ser `false`.

Mesmo que todas as propriedades de um objeto sejam iguais as de outro, eles **não são o mesmo**.

Pelo que percebi, você apenas quer verificar a existência de um item na lista validando por uma propriedade específica, então, você pode simplesmente alterar sua condição para

```
if(!item_edit.Any(it => it.item == a)) { }
```

ou

```
if(!item_edit.Exists(it => it.item == a)) { }
```

Leitura indicada: [Diferença entre Any, Contains e Exists](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103050/18246)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, alterando o codigo da condição para:

```
                if (!item_edit.Exists(x => x.item == a ))
                {
                    item_edit.Add(new Part_edit { item = a, qnt = b});
                }
```