# Diferença entre Find, Exists e Contains da classe List<T>

Tags: c#, lista

Estou trabalhando com a classe `List<T>`, então, me deparei com alguns métodos de pesquisa, se assim posso chamar:

1. `Find`;
2. `Exists`;
3. `Contains`;

Fiquei na duvida de qual a diferença entre eles, pelo que pesquisei no site da Microsoft: [List Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), Cheguei a seguinte conclusão:

1. `Find` : Procura um elemento que corresponde as definições, e retorna o primeiro valor da lista.
2. `Exists` : Determina se existe um elemento que corresponde as definições.
3. `Contains` : Determina se existe um elemento que corresponde a TODAS definiçoes.

Poderiam me dar uma explicação melhor sobre os 3 métodos? acredito que seja algum que confunda os menos experientes.

Comment: Vinculada: [Diferença entre Any, Contains e Exists](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103050/18246)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. `Find`: Procura um elemento que corresponde as definições, e retorna o primeiro valor da lista.

Correto. Melhor dizendo, que corresponde ao predicado passado como parâmetro.

> 2. `Exists`: Determina se existe um elemento que corresponde as definições.

Sim, mas idem item 1.

> 3. `Contains`: Determina se existe um elemento que corresponde a TODAS definiçoes.

Melhor seria dizer "se o elemento comparado está contido na lista ou não".

Para a comparação, normalmente é usado [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763(v=vs.110).aspx), que compara as referências dos objetos envolvidos nas iterações. Para variáveis simples funciona bem. Para objetos complexos, é recomendável escrever um comparador específico, a fim de se comparar, por exemplo, propriedade a propriedade.

Answer (score 0):

Explicando o mesmo com outras palavras.

> Find: Procura um elemento que corresponde as definições, e retorna o primeiro valor da lista.

**NÃO**. Ele retorna todos os elementos - não apenas o primeiro, ele retorna uma lista - que satisfaçam a `query` do predicado.

> Exists: Determina se existe um elemento que corresponde as definições.

Retorna `true` quando encontrar o primeiro elemento que satisfaça a `query` do predicado. Isso é importante, pois ele não rola por todos os itens da lista, mas na primeira ocorrencia, ele já retorna `true`.

> Contains: Determina se existe um elemento que corresponde a TODAS definiçoes.

Retorna `true`, não "se existe um elemento", mas sim **se existe O elemento**. O `Contains()` espera receber um objeto do mesmo tipo da lista, e retorna dizendo se aquele objeto - a mesmíssima instância do objeto - está contido ou não na lista.