# Eliminar um foreach e substituir o resultado em uma expressão lambda num método

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

A coisa é bem simples mesmo. Tenho um método que pega um nome dentro de uma base de dados e compara com o parâmetro passado no método e ser for igual, retorno ele no método, senão retorno uma `string.Empty`. Acontece, que estou tendo dificuldade de fazer em uma única linha na minha lambda. Eu fiz, mas tive preencher uma lista na lambda e depois percorrer a lisa num `foreach` e comparar item a item e sei que na minha expressão, eu posso conseguir na mesma linha e eliminar o `foreach` e o `if`. O `break` foi para não continuar após ter encontrado, posso ter uma lista grande e geraria processamento desnecessário. Veja o método abaixo:

```
private CotacaoContext contexto = new CotacaoContext();

        [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public string GetUsuarioLogin(string user)
        {
            var lista = new List<string>();
            string nomeusuario = string.Empty;
            contexto.Usuario.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(u => lista.Add(u.NMUsuario.ToList().ToString()));
            foreach (var l in lista)
            {
                if (l == user)
                {
                    nomeusuario = user;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return nomeusuario;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dá pra fazer usando o método `Any()`.

Alguns pontos importantes a notar no seu código:

- Não é necessário chamar `AsEnumerable()` e depois `ToList()`, você pode usar apenas um dos dois métodos;
- Indo ainda mais a fundo, não é necessário usar nenhum dos dois método porque não precisa materializar todos os itens do contexto para fazer esta verificação, isso é desperdício. Você pode aplicar o método `Any` diretamente no contexto e evitar que todos os dados da tabela sejam recuperados. Isso fará com que o EF gere uma *query* fazendo esta verificação e que apenas o resultado desta *query* seja retornado para a aplicação;
- O trecho `u.NMUsuario.ToList().ToString()` é desnecessário. Desde que `u.NMUsuario` seja uma `string` não é necessário convertê-lo pra lista e depois pra string de novo, é redundante.

```
private CotacaoContext contexto = new CotacaoContext();

[AcceptVerbs("Get")]
public string GetUsuarioLogin(string user)
{
    return contexto.Usuario.Any(u => u.NMUsuario == user) ? user : "";
}
```

Você pode ver mais sobre o método `Any` em: [Diferença entre Any, Contains e Exists](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103050/18246)

Comment: LINQ, esse pedaço `? user : ""` faz toda a diferença. Esses ToString(), ASEnumerable() e etc, eu coloquei pois estava dando erro, mas o que realmente faltou foi a "conclusão" da expressão, conforme falei. Muito obrigado.